# program doesn't recognize solution

Tags: java

I am trying to make simple java application which outputs two numbers on the screen and the user has to enter sum of those two numbers. When I enter the sum, if it is correct program asks me if I want continue. If I say yes, the program out puts two new numbers and when I enter correct answer the program doesn't recognize that answer is correct.

If I enter wrong answer at the start of the program I want the program to ask the user for solution over and over again until he enters correct one but I don't know how to do that. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result = getRandomNumbers();

        int counter = 1;
        char again;

        while (counter == 1) {

            int userResult = input.nextInt();
            if (result == userResult) {
                System.out.println("You are right");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are wrong, try again");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to try again? Enter y for yes or n for no");
            again = input.next().charAt(0);

            if (again == 'y') getRandomNumbers();
            else counter++;
        }

    }

    public static int getRandomNumbers() {
        SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

        int fnum = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(9);
        int snum = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(9);

        System.out.println("What is " + fnum + " times " + snum);
        return fnum * snum;
    }

}
```

Comment: First, format your code correctly, please, so human beings can see the program structure too. Until you do, I personally won't look at the code, but you may get lucky with others. Or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop to ask the user for a new input if the input is not the expected one.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        int result = getRandomNumbers();
        int userResult = input.nextInt();
        while ( result != userResult) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong, try again");
            result = getRandomNumbers();
            userResult = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("You are right");

        System.out.println("Do you want to try again? Enter y for yes or n for no");

        if (input.next().charAt(0) == 'n') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

It breaks the `while (true)` loop only if the user says that he doesn't want to continue (`n`).